Add local kotlin project to android java project in Android Studio
I'm doing a Java project targeting android 14 using Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 1.
I've found a project of gauge views that was made in Kotlin and I want to include it to my original project so I can use its libraries (it has to be local, not from git link, because I'm gonna make some changes on it).
I copied the whole external project to the root folder like this:
Folder of my project
Looking for how I could do that, i've found in here that I should include the following to my "settings.gradle.kts" file:
include("SpeedView")
But after that, the following error occurs:
"> Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'MavenRepo' was added by build file 'SpeedView\build.gradle'"
Then I've found that I should exclude the following lines from file "settings.gradle.kts":
dependencyResolutionManagement{
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories{
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

But doing so, my project doesn't compile anymore, showing the following errors:
"Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'."
Erros when compiling
Errors when compiling
I'd appreciate if someone could help me.

You should not exclude
    dependencyResolutionManagement{
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories{
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

Rather change
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)

to
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)

